# Postgres get type and domain definition

Tags: postgresql

How to get the definition of user-defined `types` and `domains` in Postgres with a query?
I need the '`create type.....`' as the output of the query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest way is to use `pg_dump` , and extract your definitions from the output.

Answer (score 0):

Just launch the pgAdmin console, Navigate to the related database in the tree, expand the desired schema in which you created the type and domain. You will be able to see the full syntax of type and domain.

Comment: But I need to have the definition of all types and domains from multiple schemas.

Comment: In that case, you need to perform the backup using pgadmin or using pg_dump and have to take dump/backup in .sql format.